# Determine an object's class returned by a factory method (Error: function does not take 1 arguments

Tags: c++, inheritance, factory-pattern

I have a factorymethod that either returns an object of  `baseclass` or one that is of `derivedclass` (a derived class of `baseclass`). The derived class has a method `virtual void foo(int x)` that takes one argument. `baseclass` however has `virtual void foo()` without an argument.

In my code, a factory method returns a pointer of type bar that definetly points to an object of class `derivedclass`. However since this is only known at runtime I get a compiler error saying that `foo()` does not take an argument.
Can I cast this pointer to a pointer of type `derivedclass`?

```
std::auto_ptr<baseclass> bar  = classfactory::CreateBar(); //returns object of class derivedclass
bar->foo(5);

class baseclass
{
 public:
      virtual void foo();
}

class derivedclass : public baseclass
{
 public:
      virtual void foo(int x);
}
```

Comment: This looks like a design problem: you should only be accessing `baseclass` methods. Having to know what type a base pointer points to defeats the purpose of polymorphism.

Comment: Also note that your base class needs to have a virtual destructor, otherwise you'll get Undefined Behaviour (probably including a memory leak) when you destroy a `derivedclass` instance through a pointer to `baseclass` (such as when `bar` goes out of scope).

Comment: OT: you should put `using baseclass::foo`. as `foo()` is hidden in `derivedclass`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question: you can use `static_cast` if you know for certain that the instance is of the proper type, or `dynamic_cast` otherwise. Something like this:

```
std::auto_ptr<baseclass> bar = classfactory::CreateBar();

if (derivedclass *der = dynamic_cast<derivedclass*>(bar.get())) {
  der->foo(5);
}
```

However, code like this generally hints at bad design. You shouldn't need to access specifics of the derived class. Perhaps the base class interface is not as complete as it should be?

Comment: This sounds very reasonable. I will change my baseclass method foo() to foo(int x)

Comment: @Angew Dependency injection across multiple interfaces on the same object is a perfect reason to use `std::dynamic_pointer_cast`.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast a `baseclass*` to a `derivedclass*`.

Using `static_cast`: if the runtime type of the `baseclass*` is not (a subclass of) `derivedclass*`, you get undefined behavior.

Using `dynamic_cast`: if the runtime type of the `baseclass*` is not (a subclass of) `derivedclass*`, the cast yields a null pointer. To allow this behaviour, additional runtime checks are performed.

Answer (score -1):

Right now your bar variable is of baseclass type, so you cannot execute foo(int x). You need convert it to appropriate type,  something like this:

```
std::auto_ptr<baseclass> bar  = classfactory::CreateBar(); //returns object of class derivedclass
std::auto_ptr<derivedclass> bar_derived(dynamic_cast<derivedclass*>(bar.get()) ? (static_cast<derivedclass*>(bar.release())) : 0 );
bar_derived->foo(5);
```

Comment: If you're not familiar with what `auto_ptr` does, you should look it up and make sure code you post is valid.

Comment: -1: This code has a double deletion problem. [Live example](http://ideone.com/cnGzRS)

Comment: Now just add a check before using `bar_derived` (it might be null), explain that `bar` gets emptied if the cast succeeds, and you have usable code.